# ElasticSearch NEST - Search on multiple types but apply filter on selected Type alone

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am looking to achieve a single query for search and filtering. But as expected when i applied filtering, the filter condition applied to all types so i got only the result of those document who have that filtered property and value .

For example,

Here i searched in 3 types (Product,Category,Manufacturer)

```
GET /my-index/Product,Category,Manufacturer/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {...}, //--> Search a word which present in all types
           "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "ProductField": "VALUE"
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i got only the result of **Product** type because Product type only contains field like **'ProductField'** and has value as **'VALUE'**.

What i am expecting is, ***with a single query***, fetch all types results(Product,Category,Manufacturer), that satisfying the search query and apply filtering only on Product.

So my doubt is

> Is there any way in Elastic search to apply filtering on specific type
>   search results alone than applying to all types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-type-query.html) query to achieve exactly that. In the filter, we have a `bool/should` clause that selects either `Category` or `Manufacturer` without any other conditions, or `Product` documents having `ProductField: VALUE`:

```
POST /my-index/Product,Category,Manufacturer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {},
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "type": {
                "value": "Category"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "value": "Manufacturer"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "type": {
                      "value": "Product"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "ProductField": "VALUE"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, One doubt, Is it mandatory to mention the types other than Product in filter query? Like you added Category and Manufacturer in the should block because I added everything in the request Uri | 

POST /my-index/Product,Category,Manufacturer/_search

Comment: Try without but also remove the `minimum_should_match` clause, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks a million for this... took a long time to dig this thread up, but it's ultimately exactly what I needed.